# How can I link my CSS file to all PHP/HTML files in different folders with a complex directory structure?

Tags: php, html, css, directory, path

CSS and PHP Pathing.

So, i just want to link my CSS to all my PHP/HTML files, but i have a few folders including one containing two folders, containing PHPs. Heres the structure.

```
localhost
    └── HC (Main folder)
        └── styles.css
        └── Logica (folder)
        │         │ 
        │         ├── file1.php
        │         └── file2.php
        │ 
        └── Maestra (folder)
        │         │ 
        │         ├── file3.php
        │         └── file4.php
        │ 
        └── Paginas (folder)
                  │
                  ├── file5.php
                  └────── Usuario (folder)
                  │         │
                  │         ├── file6.php
                  │         └── file7.php
                  └────── Ventas (folder)
                            │
                            ├── file8.php
                            └── file9.php
                            └── file10.php
                            └── file11.php
```

On the Maestra folder, the 2 files contained are the master page header and footer that needs to share the CSS to the contained PHP files, but if lets say, we go to file9.php and then navigate to the different php files, if i use "../" or "../../" and etc, it will run into a problem where the url concatenation will result in something like this:

```
/localhost/HC/Paginas/HC/Paginas/Ventas/file8.php
```

but that path doesnt exist.

Is and there a way for all the PHP (all of them mostly have HTML/PHP) files to share the same path for the CSS? Like an absolute path compatible with every different.
(Im having trouble too with setting the path for the navbar buttons because of the folder levels difference)
If not, is there a solution for it?

Comment: Use absolute paths instead of relative paths

Comment: I could be wrong but the absolute paths examples that i saw adapting them to my proyect doesnt work for me, Can you show me an example?

Comment: just link to the css file http://localhost/HC/style.css

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/HC/styles.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Akam kind of solved the problem by using the following ref.

```
> http://localhost/HC/.../file.php
```

I still wanted to have a way to construct the path by a function or some implemented method that designs the path depending on the location, because i want to link the different pages on my proyect in general and using this workaround affects the delivery behavior of AJAX - POST when the PHP file is requesting it.